# Using Aggregate function in select statement

Tags: oracle

Is there a way we can use an aggregate function inside a CASE statement as part of the same select ?
When i run the query below i get the following error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function".

```
    SELECT 
    A.id id,
    SUM(B.quantity) quantity ,
   MAX(CASE WHEN nvl(A.threshold,0) > SUM(B.quantity) THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END )  late 
  FROM 
    TableB B ,
    TableA A 
     WHERE B.Type in ('ATYPE,'BTYPE') AND  A.nKey = B.id 
     GROUP BY 
    A.id
```

### Table B

```
id  quantity  Type
9      10   Type A
9      11   Type B
10     5     Type A
```

### Table A

```
id  nkey   threshold
1      9    15
2      10   10
```

### Result

```
id  quantity  late
1      21   F
2      5    T
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the aggregate function for threshold or add threshold in the group by list:

either replace `nvl(A.threshold,0)` with `min(nvl(A.threshold,0))`

or

use the following `GROUP BY`:

```
group by a.id, a.threshold
```